# Rotate Function for Component Drawed with Canvas Lazarus

Tags: freepascal

I need a function in Lazarus that with it I can rotate some components instead of rewrite them (swapping x with y and viceversa)
for example:

i am using a class developed by another user
with this class i had to define the name of the component with properties and after a procedure NameComponent.Draw
the motedi engine draw the components reading this Draw procedure.
i save the components on a file sch (with also wires junction resistors etc)
when i load a circuit ...my software creates components (also wires junction) with saved properties (include points of connection where wire is attached)
wires has also node property
my software creates the netlist etc

```
procedure SW.Draw;
var angle:extended;
begin


if (self.Orientamento = '') or (self.Orientamento = '1') then
begin
  v2d.setpen(pssolid,1,clBlue);
  v2d.SetBrush(clwhite);
  v2d.Line(x,y+30,x+100,y+30);
  v2d.line(x,y+30,x,y+120);
  v2d.line(x,y+120,x+100,y+120);
  v2d.line(x+100,y+30,x+100,y+120);
  v2d.line(x+20,y+30,x+20,y+10);     // nc-
  v2d.line(x+80,y+30,x+80,y+10);     // nc+

  v2d.line(x+20,y+120,x+20,y+140);     // n-
  v2d.line(x+80,y+120,x+80,y+140);     // n+


  // interruttore dentro
  v2d.line(x+20,y+120,x+20,y+80);    // a
  v2d.line(x+80,y+120,x+80,y+80);    // b
  v2d.line(x+20,y+80,x+40,y+80);     // c
  v2d.line(x+60,y+80,x+80,y+80);     // d

  if (self.State = 'OFF') then
  begin
    v2d.setpen(pssolid,2,clGreen);
    v2d.line(x+40,y+80,x+63,y+72);      // e
  end
  else
  begin
    v2d.setpen(pssolid,2,clGreen);
    v2d.line(x+40,y+80,x+60,y+80);
  end;
  v2d.setpen(pssolid,1,clBlue);
  v2d.SetText(clRed, 6,'', true);
  v2d.Texto(X+82, Y +110, 'N+');
  v2d.Texto(X+74, Y +35, 'NC+');
  v2d.SetText(clBlack, 6,'', true);
  v2d.Texto(X+22, Y +110, 'N-');
  v2d.Texto(X+15, Y +35, 'NC-');
  v2d.SetText(clBlack, 8,'', true);
  v2d.Texto(x+104,y+35, self.Nome);
  v2d.Texto(x+104,y+50, self.VT);
  v2d.Texto(x+104,y+65, self.VH);
  v2d.Texto(x+104,y+80, self.RON);
  v2d.Texto(x+104,y+95, self.ROFF);

end;


if (self.Orientamento = '2') then
begin
  v2d.setpen(pssolid,1,clBlue);
  v2d.SetBrush(clwhite);
  v2d.line(x+30,y,x+30,y+100);
  v2d.line(x+30,y,x+120,y);
  v2d.line(x+120,y,x+120,y+100);
  v2d.line(x+30,y+100,x+120,y+100);
  v2d.line(x+30,y+20,x+10,y+20);  // nc-
  v2d.line(x+30,y+80,x+10,y+80); // nc +
  v2d.line(x+120,y+20, x+140,y+20); // n-
  v2d.line(x+120,y+80,x+140,y+80); // n+
  v2d.line(x+120, y+20, x+80, y+20);
  v2d.line(x+120,y+80,x+80,y+80);
  v2d.line(x+80, y+20, x+80, y+40);
  v2d.line(x+80, y+60, x+80, y+80);


  if (self.State = 'OFF') then
  begin
    v2d.setpen(pssolid,2,clGreen);
//    v2d.line(x+80, y+40, x+72, y+63);
    v2d.line(x+80, y+60, x+72, y+37);
  end
  else
  begin
    v2d.setpen(pssolid,2,clGreen);
    v2d.line(x+80,y+60, x+80, y+40);
//    v2d.line(x+80, y+40, x+80, y+60);
  end;


  v2d.setpen(pssolid,1,clBlue);
  v2d.SetText(clBlack, 6,'', true);
  v2d.texto(x+110, y+82, 'N-');
  v2d.texto(x+35, y+74, 'NC-');
  v2d.SetText(clRed, 6,'', true);
  v2d.Texto(x+110, y+22, 'N+');
  v2d.Texto(x+35, y+15, 'NC+');




end;

inherited;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're asking for code, that's supports degrees instead of pre-defined values, here's an example, which uses Math PI to perform sectoral rotation of a point on 2-dimensional space:

```
    function findCenter(Width, Height: Integer): TPoint;
    begin
         // Specify rotation center
         Result := TPoint.Create(Width DIV 2, Height DIV 2);
    end;
    function Rotate(What, Center: TPoint; Angle: Double): TPoint; overload;
    begin
    if Angle > 0 then
    begin
      // Perform rotation
      Result.X :=
                 ROUND(
                       Center.X + (What.X - Center.X)* COS(Angle)
                               - (What.Y - Center.Y)* SIN(Angle) );
      Result.Y :=
                 ROUND(
                       Center.X + (What.X - Center.X)* SIN(Angle)
                               + (What.Y - Center.Y)* COS(Angle) );
    end
    else
        Result := TPoint.Create(What);
    end;
    function Rotate(What, Center: TPoint; Degrees: Integer): TPoint; overload;
    var RotationAngle: Double;
    begin
      // Convert Degress to Radians
      RotationAngle := Degrees * PI/180;
      Result := Rotate(What, Center, RotationAngle);
    end;
    function Rotate(What: TPoint; Degrees: Integer): TPoint; overload;
    var RotationAngle: Double;
    begin
      RotationAngle := Degrees * PI/180;
      Result := Rotate(What, TPoint.Create(0,0), RotationAngle);
    end;
```

Use the function Rotate() to rotate the location of your elements, for each of them you need to specify also a center of an element (Width and Height of parent  element, divided by 2), information to get the center of element for text you can gather from WinAPI ( CalcTextWidth or CalcTextRect either )
The actual height of the text is the Font.Size - 1, so you can get Height value without external functions.

Note, that this probably won't work, if you're resizing your polygons, to resize them you need to calculate relations between every point or to split polygons to the triangles and do it for them (every n-heighted polygon can be splitted to triangles, the exception is ellipse, which has its own sizing technique - modifying the diameter ).
Also, be aware, that you must calculate new area sizes and positions offsets in order to keep final picture in field of view.